# JSONDecodeError: Extra data occurring when trying to json.load large file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, debugging

I'm pulling this error when I run this string of code and I'm not sure how to interpret it. After research I still don't know the problem. Does anyone know what's going on.

Here is the code:

```
import json, sys

with open('/Users/mac/Desktop/export-2017-04-28-0235-25014395ac.json', 'r',
          encoding='utf-8') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
print(d)
```

Also, I'm wondering if the JSON size is the problem. It's about 200mb.

Here's the error now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/untitled.py", line 5, in <module>
    d = json.load(json_data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 15629)
[Finished in 1.5s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python3 -OO -u "/Users/mac/Desktop/untitled.py"]
[dir: /Users/mac/Desktop]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Comment: It's not a valid JSON file; there is extra data past the end of whatever object it contains.  Look at the file in a text editor, the problem is likely to be obvious.